# How to open .hprof file

Tags: java

I am running a Java application and faced an error Out of memory. .hprof file is generated. What do I use to analyse what's in the file? How to read that file?
Any suggestion?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/707609/hpjmeter-like-graphical-tool-to-view-agentlibhprof-profiling-output.

Comment: though it is duplicate it is on top of search results ))

Answer (score 14):

[Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is the best tool I found for that. It's free and very efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Java heap analyser tool as well as MAT . But MAT is the best for finding memory leaks IMO .